# Wondering if the following sentence is completely written in English

Tags: word-meaning

I found it on [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rouhi)

> I love u so much ur **rouhi**

While I understand the acronyms used there, I have my doubts whether the word **rouhi** is an English word? Do native speakers of English use the word **rouhi**? According to the link below they do! But I am doubtful.

Could you reply to my question in simple English. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *ur* is the textspeak spelling of *you are*, or *you're*, or *your*. This question appears to be off-topic because it is about textspeak, not Standard English.

Comment: @StoneyB  I will edit the question , my reall concern is the word rouhi

Comment: Your link explains the meaning. *Rouhi* is Arabic for *my soul* (I assume that's right; I don't know Arabic). What don't you understand?

Comment: You answered yourself! :)

Comment: Your own link indicates that it comes from _Arabic_, not English. In several sociolects of English, words are borrowed from other languages, but that does not mean they are used or widely understood outside that sociolect (actually, the use of such "secret" words is often a property of a sociolect).

Comment: Isn't it something like the word "bouquet" that I am sure has entered in English from French, and now is considered as an English word?

Comment: [Please do not cross-post to ELL and ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182829/is-the-word-rouhi-a-valid-word-in-english), particularly without telling anyone you're doing so.  It's rather inconsiderate.

Answer (score 3):

We can figure out whether this word is used in English by checking corpora:

1. Searching [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rouhi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), we find **zero results**.
2. Searching the [Corpus of Global Web-based English (GloWbE)](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=31894774), we find **five results**, two of which are basically duplicates, all of which are names.
3. Searching [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rouhi%22), we find your cross-posts on ELL and ELU and the Urban Dictionary entry, but apart from these, every instance seems to be a name.

So no, *rouhi* does **not** appear to a word that English speakers use, generally speaking.  Note that your Urban Dictionary link is not evidence to the contrary—there's no reason to believe the person who created the entry was a native speaker of English.

Comment: I agree with (and have upvoted) this answer. I just wanted to add that English does adopt words from other languages, and sometimes it takes awhile for dictionaries to catch up. Your three tests show that _rouhi_ isn't even close to working its way into the vernacular, and therefore won't be considered an English word any time soon – at least not formally. Hors d'oeuvres, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The word **ur**  indicates **your**. It is informal texting form of **your** .

And **rouhi** is not an English word it is an Arabic word which means **soul or spirit**.